# How to identifying zones overlaps (Intersect)?

Tags: buffer, overlay, intersection, r-sf

I have a data set of parks for an area and have created buffers of 250 and 500m. I want to identify zones overlaps (intersections) of my two created layers.

```
b500 %>% st_intersects

# Intersection - to get places with the biggest choice
b500.int <- b500 %>% st_intersection()
```

b500 represents my buffer of 500m  for my parks.

When I try run this code I get Error in CPL_nary_intersection(x). I have tried using st_set_precision() to fix this but it doesn't work

Comment: I guess the problem comes from the fact that you have only one argument in your function. You have to specify each of the two polygons as arguments. 
If I take your example, you should write the code as follows: 
`st_intersection(b500, b250)`

Comment: You are able to use `st_intersection()` on a single object - this returns areas where it self-intersects, which I suspect is what @scumbagsurfer wants to do. I have posted an example of this.

Answer (score 2):

`st_intersection()` can be used for 2 different things (see [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_ops.html)):

1. Finding the self-intersection of a geometry collection
2. Finding the intersection between 2 separate geometries

As an example, let's use the `nz` data from the `spData` package. It comes with 16 separate `POLYGON` features, one for each region (*like* a state). First up, we use `st_union()` and `st_cast()` to combine features which touch, leaving us with a separate features for each island.

```
# make an island version of nz
nz %>% 
  st_union %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>% 
  st_sf %>% 
  {. ->> nz_islands}

# plot it  
nz_islands %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

To demonstrate option 1 (finding self-intersection), let's buffer each feature by 50,000 m (50 km) using `st_buffer()`. This returns a new collection of features and includes a new column `n.overlaps` indicating how many features overlap in each feature. If you want the self-intersection, you keep features where `n.overlaps > 1`.

```
# now, whats the (self) intersection between a buffered version
nz_islands %>% 
  st_buffer(50000) %>% 
  st_intersection %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = nz_islands)+
  geom_sf(aes(fill = factor(n.overlaps)), alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

In this figure, areas other than those filled red overlap with other features in the collection.

To demonstrate point 2 (intersection between 2 geometries), we can use 2 buffered versions of `nz_islands`.

```
st_intersection(
  nz_islands %>% st_buffer(25000),
  nz_islands %>% st_buffer(50000)
) %>% 
  st_union %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = nz_islands, linetype = 'longdash')+
  geom_sf(data = nz_islands %>% st_buffer(50000), fill = NA, linetype = 'dashed')+
  geom_sf(fill = 'red', alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

However, the coloured area is the same as the smaller buffered version, as the version with the larger buffer is just an expanded version of the smaller one. So, employing option 2 on features which are the same other than a buffer width isn't that useful in this situation.

Rather, let's find the intersection between buffered versions of the north and south islands (features 5 and 3).

```
st_intersection(
  nz_islands[5,] %>% st_buffer(50000),
  nz_islands[3,] %>% st_buffer(50000)
) %>% 
  st_union %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = nz_islands)+
  geom_sf(data = nz_islands[5,] %>% st_buffer(50000), linetype = 'dashed', fill = NA)+
  geom_sf(data = nz_islands[3,] %>% st_buffer(50000), linetype = 'dashed', fill = NA)+
  geom_sf(fill = 'red', alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

Without knowing the structure of your data or your expected results, I suspect you want to use option 1 for the intersection of parks in a single collection. I can't help with your error without knowing what your data looks like, but if you follow this example you should be able to do it.